# Forcing the fit of a nonlinear piecewise function to be continuous

Tags: fitting, data, piecewise

I am trying to fit some data

```
data = {{100, 114}, {200, 1342}, {300, 36604}, {400, 44279}, {500, 
    10243}, {600, 4103}, {700, 3080}, {800, 2636}, {900, 2254}, {1000,
     1909}, {1100, 1821}, {1200, 1620}, {1300, 1436}, {1400, 
    1319}, {1500, 1175}, {1600, 1158}, {1700, 1094}, {1800, 
    975}, {1900, 884}, {2000, 865}, {2100, 806}, {2200, 721}, {2300, 
    630}, {2400, 634}, {2500, 650}, {2600, 530}, {2700, 498}, {2800, 
    465}, {2900, 462}, {3000, 400}, {3100, 442}, {3200, 376}, {3300, 
    364}, {3400, 362}, {3500, 305}, {3600, 292}, {3700, 313}, {3800, 
    292}, {3900, 240}, {4000, 243}, {4100, 281}, {4200, 230}, {4300, 
    231}, {4400, 229}, {4500, 227}, {4600, 208}, {4700, 215}, {4800, 
    182}, {4900, 176}, {5000, 191}, {5100, 187}, {5200, 177}, {5300, 
    170}, {5400, 170}, {5500, 157}, {5600, 135}, {5700, 120}, {5800, 
    154}, {5900, 162}, {6000, 118}, {6100, 131}, {6200, 116}, {6300, 
    142}, {6400, 142}, {6500, 157}, {6600, 135}, {6700, 151}, {6800, 
    172}, {6900, 128}, {7000, 126}, {7100, 117}, {7200, 113}, {7300, 
    127}, {7400, 120}, {7500, 114}, {7600, 132}, {7700, 133}, {7800, 
    140}, {7900, 107}, {8000, 135}, {8100, 163}, {8200, 117}, {8300, 
    118}, {8400, 103}, {8500, 111}, {8600, 107}, {8700, 126}, {8800, 
    89}, {8900, 109}, {9000, 107}, {9100, 127}, {9200, 101}, {9300, 
    101}, {9400, 107}, {9500, 116}, {9600, 111}, {9700, 109}, {9800, 
    110}, {9900, 111}, {10000, 97}, {10100, 88}, {10200, 107}, {10300,
     110}, {10400, 104}, {10500, 120}, {10600, 95}, {10700, 
    100}, {10800, 108}, {10900, 96}, {11000, 103}, {11100, 
    116}, {11200, 127}, {11300, 152}, {11400, 98}, {11500, 
    95}, {11600, 93}, {11700, 112}, {11800, 151}, {11900, 
    132}, {12000, 129}, {12100, 116}, {12200, 128}, {12300, 
    148}, {12400, 110}, {12500, 127}, {12600, 159}, {12700, 
    140}, {12800, 98}, {12900, 95}, {13000, 98}};
dataPlot = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot of the list data]

using a piecewise function consisting of a Gaussian function for $t < 600$ and an exponential function for $t \geq 600$. I've used FindFit and plotted the function on top of the data:

```
f2[t_, t0_, \[Sigma]_, t1_, \[Tau]_] := 
 Piecewise[{{A Exp[-((t - t0)/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma]))^2], 
    t < 600}, {B Exp[-(t - t1)/\[Tau]], t >= 600}}]
FindFit[data, 
 f2[t, t0, \[Sigma], 
  t1, \[Tau]], {{t0, 400}, {\[Sigma], 100}, {t1, 600}, {\[Tau], 
   1000}, {A, 45000}, {B, 4000}}, t, 
 NormFunction -> (Norm[#1, Infinity] & )]
f2Fit[t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{45000*Exp[-((t - 360.003)/(Sqrt[2] 66.0556))^2], 
    t < 600}, {4000*Exp[-(t - 600)/1000], t >= 600}}]
fitPlot = 
  Plot[f2Fit[t], {t, 0, 13000}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
Show[{dataPlot, fitPlot}]
```

[image: The fitted curve plotted on top of the data points]
but I am having some trouble getting the function to be continuous. I have tried tweaking parameters of the fit but this is very time consuming and doesn't work well. Is there a way I can force the FindFit function to generate a continuous piecewise function? Or is there another routine I can use to generate such a function?

Comment: I need the function to be continuous because I am trying to deconvolve it with another function and want to minimize as much noise as possible in the deconvolution.

Comment: If you want the function to be continuous (but not necessarily having the derivative to be continuous) at $t=600$, then you need to have $A \exp \left(-\left(\frac{t-\text{t0}}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)^2\right)=B \exp \left(-\frac{t-\text{t1}}{\tau }\right)$ when $t=600$.  That means there will be some restrictions among the parameters.   Using `Reduce` on that equality suggests that using $\tau=-\frac{2 \sigma ^2 (t_1-600)}{2 \sigma ^2 \log \left(\frac{B}{A}\right)+t_0^2-1200 t_0+360000}$ would do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{100, 114}, {200, 1342}, {300, 36604}, {400, 44279}, {500, 
    10243}, {600, 4103}, {700, 3080}, {800, 2636}, {900, 2254}, {1000, 
    1909}, {1100, 1821}, {1200, 1620}, {1300, 1436}, {1400, 1319}, {1500, 
    1175}, {1600, 1158}, {1700, 1094}, {1800, 975}, {1900, 884}, {2000, 
    865}, {2100, 806}, {2200, 721}, {2300, 630}, {2400, 634}, {2500, 
    650}, {2600, 530}, {2700, 498}, {2800, 465}, {2900, 462}, {3000, 
    400}, {3100, 442}, {3200, 376}, {3300, 364}, {3400, 362}, {3500, 
    305}, {3600, 292}, {3700, 313}, {3800, 292}, {3900, 240}, {4000, 
    243}, {4100, 281}, {4200, 230}, {4300, 231}, {4400, 229}, {4500, 
    227}, {4600, 208}, {4700, 215}, {4800, 182}, {4900, 176}, {5000, 
    191}, {5100, 187}, {5200, 177}, {5300, 170}, {5400, 170}, {5500, 
    157}, {5600, 135}, {5700, 120}, {5800, 154}, {5900, 162}, {6000, 
    118}, {6100, 131}, {6200, 116}, {6300, 142}, {6400, 142}, {6500, 
    157}, {6600, 135}, {6700, 151}, {6800, 172}, {6900, 128}, {7000, 
    126}, {7100, 117}, {7200, 113}, {7300, 127}, {7400, 120}, {7500, 
    114}, {7600, 132}, {7700, 133}, {7800, 140}, {7900, 107}, {8000, 
    135}, {8100, 163}, {8200, 117}, {8300, 118}, {8400, 103}, {8500, 
    111}, {8600, 107}, {8700, 126}, {8800, 89}, {8900, 109}, {9000, 
    107}, {9100, 127}, {9200, 101}, {9300, 101}, {9400, 107}, {9500, 
    116}, {9600, 111}, {9700, 109}, {9800, 110}, {9900, 111}, {10000, 
    97}, {10100, 88}, {10200, 107}, {10300, 110}, {10400, 104}, {10500, 
    120}, {10600, 95}, {10700, 100}, {10800, 108}, {10900, 96}, {11000, 
    103}, {11100, 116}, {11200, 127}, {11300, 152}, {11400, 98}, {11500, 
    95}, {11600, 93}, {11700, 112}, {11800, 151}, {11900, 132}, {12000, 
    129}, {12100, 116}, {12200, 128}, {12300, 148}, {12400, 110}, {12500, 
    127}, {12600, 159}, {12700, 140}, {12800, 98}, {12900, 95}, {13000, 98}};

{tmin, tmax} = MinMax@data[[All, 1]];
```

Use [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), make the transition value a parameter, and include a constraint for continuity at the transition value.

```
f2[t_, t0_, σ_, t1_, τ_, trans_] := 
 Piecewise[{{A Exp[-((t - t0)/(Sqrt[2] σ))^2], 
    t < trans}, {B Exp[-(t - t1)/τ], t >= trans}}]

(nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {f2[t, t0, σ, t1, τ, trans],
     A Exp[-((trans - t0)/(Sqrt[2] σ))^2] == 
      B Exp[-(trans - t1)/τ]},
    {{t0, 400}, {σ, 100}, {t1, 600}, {τ, 1000}, {A, 45000}, {B, 
      4000}, {trans, 600}}, t]) // Normal
```

[image]

```
Plot[nlm[t], {t, tmin, tmax},
 PlotStyle -> Red,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotRange -> All,
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Plot[nlm[t], {t, 520, 560},
     PlotStyle -> Red,
     PlotPoints -> 100,
     MaxRecursion -> 5,
     PlotLabel -> "model is continuous"]],
   AbsolutePointSize[2], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

```
nlm["Properties"]

{"AdjustedRSquared", "AIC", "AICc", "ANOVATable", \
"ANOVATableDegreesOfFreedom", "ANOVATableEntries", \
"ANOVATableMeanSquares", "ANOVATableSumsOfSquares", "BestFit", \
"BestFitParameters", "BIC", "CorrelationMatrix", "CovarianceMatrix", \
"CurvatureConfidenceRegion", "Data", "EstimatedVariance", \
"FitCurvatureTable", "FitCurvatureTableEntries", "FitResiduals", \
"Function", "HatDiagonal", "MaxIntrinsicCurvature", \
"MaxParameterEffectsCurvature", "MeanPredictionBands", \
"MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals", \
"MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTable", \
"MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries", \
"MeanPredictionErrors", "ParameterBias", \
"ParameterConfidenceIntervals", "ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable", \
"ParameterConfidenceIntervalTableEntries", \
"ParameterConfidenceRegion", "ParameterErrors", "ParameterPValues", \
"ParameterTable", "ParameterTableEntries", "ParameterTStatistics", \
"PredictedResponse", "Properties", "Response", "RSquared", \
"SingleDeletionVariances", "SinglePredictionBands", \
"SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervals", \
"SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTable", \
"SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries", \
"SinglePredictionErrors", "StandardizedResiduals", \
"StudentizedResiduals"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think to set the transition value as a fit parameter but that seems like an obvious solution now. What are the differences between NonlinearModelFit and FindFit?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` has many properties and diagnostics. See the documentation.